# What's the best empty basket page/message for e-commerce?

Tags: e-commerce, user-centered-design, shopping-cart, conversion-rate

I'm looking for e-commerce experience and I really think that just show a message saying your cart is empty is so boring. I feel that we must show something more interactive for the users.

**What's the better empty shopping cart message/page that you've seen?**
Do you have some data/statistics about empty shopping cart conversion?

Look what I designed and give me your opinion which one should works better, please.

*PS.: My user has between 25-55 years, most part male and are buying roofing materials. The sales process is not so short, not so impulsive and sometimes the user can add products to the cart, leave and back in the further, and not always they cart still there (if they don't save).*

**Option 1)** All empty and none value with some opacity but looks like the real shopping cart. Simulate where will be the products and show button to go to the homepage.
[image]

**Option 2)**  All empty and none value with some opacity but looks like the real shopping cart. Funny image to be not so boring.
[image]

**Option 3)** All empty and none value with some opacity but looks like the real shopping cart. Show last seen products.
[image]

**Considering all discussed and the template options. Which one do you consider better?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is my feedback to the all three options:

1. The message in the red box states that something is wrong, however, it isn't. The button "+Add products" doesn't represent the actual action, because no products will be added when the user hits it. The dummy items below add visual complexity to the page, which is confusing.
2. The message about the empty cart is better than in the first option, but the red icon still indicates that there is something wrong. An image in this example doesn't represent the emptiness of the cart. The user should use the top navigation to go back to the shop, which means that he should change his locus of attention (refer to Jef Raskin - The Humane Interface Chapter 2.3)
3. Same wrong message as in option one and space below is filled with the items, which may be irrelevant to the user needs.

I would recommend you to refer to an example below:

- The page is simple and clean
- The message is large and clear, and it doesn't mean that there is something wrong
- The image that represents an empty cart
- A button with a clear statement, which will get the user back to the shop

[image]

Comment: Good viewpoint but I'm not 100% convinced that default empty message is enough because we still not saying what the user should do or helping them to find what they are looking for. I will just wait for some more answers to compare. Thanks!

Comment: The aim of the shopping cart is to review the items and do a checkout. Helping a user to find what they are looking for is the purpose of the shop page. Splitting the functions between the pages helps the user to perform one task at a time, which basically provides a better experience.

Comment: I agree! And what can I do to help the user that arrives at the empty shopping cart and are asking in his mind: Where are my products?

Comment: And one more question, why I can't try to sell something for the user in the shopping cart if I try to sell something everywhere on e-commerce?

Comment: To solve the problem, we should find out the reason. Does it take a while for users to finish their purchase, therefore their shopping cart can be deleted after some inactive time if they haven't saved it? If so, then the reason is that users are unaware that unsaved carts will be deleted and you should help users to save their carts, or at least to inform them that the cart will be deleted. Is that's right?

Comment: I agree but unfortunately, the world is not perfect. I'm adding a save button and highlighting on shopping cart page but I sure that some of them will not read it. Because of this, I'm trying to find alternative ways. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: You can display items you want to sell in the shopping cart, or anywhere else, but think about its effectiveness.

Comment: I think, that your empty cart should explain to the user what happened with his items. For example "... if you had items in your cart, they were wiped due to long inactivity. But hey! You can start from the clean sheet!" - and there should be a button.

Answer (score 0):

I like 3 except that the views should be below and include a pending list or wish list / shopping list first and what the user looked at second. When I go into a place to shop I really hate it when I have to leave the shopping mode to enter something into my cart. I want to say add to cart and keep shopping. Sometimes I run into something that I want to research or wait till I get more funding - the wish list is good for that. 
You might consider giving the user a place to add a list of things they want to consider. Let me type in what I can remember so I can add to the list as I go. But make it easy to select which items I put into the shopping cart. And make certain that I don't have to go to another page each time I say add to cart - what a pain that is!